# Magento Upgrade 1.5.1 to 1.6.2 - Column "base_shipping_hidden_tax_amount" does not exists on table "sales_flat_creditmemo"

Tags: magento

I've got the following error while updating the sql database from magento versin 1.5.1 to 1.6.2:

```
"html/magento/magento16/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php" - 
Column "base_shipping_hidden_tax_amount" does not exists on table "sales_flat_creditmemo"";i:1;s:1164:"#0
```

Answer (score 3):

**The Solution:**

So I've opened the table and saw a spelling mistake in the column name:

[image]

So it's only required to rename the column:

```
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo` CHANGE `base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt` `base_shipping_hidden_tax_amount` DECIMAL(12,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Shipping Hidden Tax Amount'
```

Then you can re-run you're magento store. Good luck with the next errors ... :)

Comment: Afterwards, if migrating to 2.x be sure to rename it again ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055922/magento-2-migration-tool-destination-fields-are-not-mapped

Answer (score 2):

There's actually no need to rename that field because there's already an old field mapping done in app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml. You just have to refresh the page to continue with the upgrade. And if it's not working just continue refreshing.
Here's some piece of the old field mapping code:

`<sales>
  <old_fields_map>
    <order>             <payment_authorization_expiration>payment_auth_expiration</payment_authorization_expiration>
                    <forced_do_shipment_with_invoice>forced_shipment_with_invoice</forced_do_shipment_with_invoice>
                    <base_shipping_hidden_tax_amount>base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt</base_shipping_hidden_tax_amount>
    </order>
  </old_fields_map>`

Comment: What do you do if the Admin panel continuously gives you a Report screen. Refreshed about 20 times and it still showed.