# Magento 2 - Migration tool - Destination fields are not mapped

Tags: magento, migration, data-migration, magento2

I'm trying to use the Data Migration Tool to migrate a site from 1.9.2.2 to 2.0.5. I was able to solve numerous 'Source fields not mapped' errors editing the map.xml file, but can't shift the error;

```
Destination fields are not mapped. Document: sales_creditmemo. Fields: base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt
```

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLT5T.jpg)

I've tried adding;

```
        <ignore>
            <document>sales_creditmemo.base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt</document>
        </ignore>
```

Within destination> document_rules>

and

```
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_creditmemo.base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt</field>
        </ignore>
```

Within field_rules > source>.

But it won't go away. I'm happy to ignore this value, as credit memos weren't used by the store.

Many thanks for any help, I've been hitting this wall for a few hours now.

==============================================================

## SOLVED

I finally managed to solve it by comparing the two tables and found that sales_flat_creditmemo.base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt had been renamed to sales_flat_creditmemo.base_shipping_hidden_tax_amount to fix an upgrade issue for Magento 1.6

Renaming 'tax_amnt' fixed it and it seems that the original mapping issue in 1.6 has been resolved, so the site still works.